# How to configure ELB load-balancer over HTTPS for two sites deployed to the same pair of servers?

Tags: amazon-ec2, iis, load-balancing, https, amazon-elb

I would appreciate immensely if you shed some light into what we might be missing or doing wrong. I am not completely in charge of the configuration, and I'm not an expert on the subject, but have been working with our systems team trying to resolve this issue to no avail:

1. We have two sites, `main.my-company.com` and `admin.my-company.com` both of which we need to serve **over HTTPS** and be **load-balanced**.
2. Each site has its own load-balancer, `LB-Main` and `LB-Admin`. Each of these load-balancers is already configured with our wildcard SSL certificate `*.my-company.com` on port `:443`
3. **Both sites need to be deployed to the same pair of servers. This is a business constraint.**
4. Our DNS is configured so that `main.my-company.com` points to `LB-Main` and `admin.my-company.com` points to `LB-Admin`
5. `LB-Main` forwards traffic through `https://main.my-company.com:443/` to port `:4443` on the VMs. Our Main site on is configured on IIS with bindings `{http:*:4443:}` on each server.
6. `LB-Admin` forwards traffic through `https://admin.my-company.com:443/` to port `:4444` on the VMs. Our Admin site on is configured on IIS with bindings `{http:*:4444:}` on each server.
7. All ports are appropriately open on the servers. (`:4443`, `:4444` and even `:443` and `:80`, which are not used.)
8. All health-check endpoints used by **ELB** return `HTTP/1.x 200 OK`

Our problem is that when actually trying `https://main.my-company.com/` or `https://main.my-company.com:443/` the request times out.

It's as if our dual SSL configuration for both load-balancers conflicts with one another, because when only one of the hosts uses SSL, the other works fine on port `:80`

What might we be missing or doing wrong?

Comment: *when only one of the hosts uses SSL, the other works fine on port 80*  I'm a little unclear on what this means.   Connecting multiple ELBs to the same instance or instances is a valid configuration, though.  I have one set of instances with 15 different ELBs attached to all of them.  The ELB logs and the instance web server logs, and `netstat`, would be the places to look, as well as hitting the instances directly, using `openssl s_client -connect ...`.

Comment: Do your EC2 instances' Security Groups allow connections from your ELBs to those 4443/4444 ports?  Are there any on-instance firewalls that might be blocking connections from the ELBs to the 4443/4444 ports?  Are your ELBs configured with HTTPS listeners on port 443 on the frontend?

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. I'll answer in order: @Michael-sqlbot - basically what I mean is that if `LB-Main` receives traffic on `:80` and forwards to `:80` and `LB-Admin` receives traffic on `:443` and forwards to `:443` then everything is fine. It's our attempt to connect 2 ELBs to the instances over HTTPS at which we are not being successful.

Comment: I think both my suggestions and those of @Castaglia still stand.  Verify that the security group of the instances allows access to those ports from the ELB.  Verify that the instances are responding to direct requests on those ports using `openssl s_client` or `curl` from another machine.  There's nothing intrinsically flawed or unsupported with what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Castaglia - Our SysAdmin was well aware of the security groups and there is no problem reaching the instances from the ELBs. As I said, we can see the health-check endpoints being successfully reached on the corresponding ports `:4443` and `:4444`... And yeah, both our ELBs do listen to `:443`.

Comment: What does `openssl s_client -connect <instance-ip-addr>:4443` show, for one of the instances?

Comment: Yeah, we can actually even *browse* to the health-check endpoints over HTTPS directly (by using `https://<ip-address>:4443/IsAlive` for example). The original goal of supporting both `:80` and `:443` at `LB-Main` was to implement SSL offloading. As such we have also tried it and enabled `:80` on the instances. Our SysAdmin has pointed that ELBs are Level 4 load-balancers and as such we cannot achieve redirection of at the ELB level. In either case, either configuration is not working.

Comment: @Castaglia - we are on Windows environment as such we are more inclined to Windows tools. As I said, browsers confirm `HTTP 200 OK` from those boxes. At the boxes themselves we have installed Wireshark, and we can see the request arriving from our explicit pings. To tell you the truth we cannot tell the exactly where the traffic is stalled when browsing to `https://main.my-company.com` but we never see anything coming to either box. We even shut down one of the VMs,

Comment: Are your ELBs and EC2 instances in the same VPCs?  Or perhaps in different public (or private) subnets?